# DragHandle Not working in TableDnD JQuery Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, tablednd

I am using tablednd plugin to drag and drop my table rows everything works fine for me but when I try to use the DragHandle property then neither the rows are dragable nor the hander comes

My Script is as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#sort').tableDnD({
                onDrop: function(table, row) {
                  alert(row.id);
                }, 
                            dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
            });
        });
        </script>
```

When I remove the drag handle then it works and when I include it it does not work.

Any Ideas why its not working

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might be using an older version (probably Version 0.4).

I had the same issue after downloading the plug-in from GitHub. Seems like you get served the old version, and not the current 0.7

By the way:
dragHandle: ***".dragHandle"***
is correct!

Comment: `    $('#table-5').tableDnD({
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
            alert($('#table-5').tableDnDSerialize());
        },
        dragHandle: "dragHandle"
    });`    
This is taken directly from the author's site: http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

Comment: The GitHub code linked to from several sites is out of date, and doesn't support dragHandle. This is the correct answer.

Comment: You can find later versions here: https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/tree/master/js

Answer (score 2):

Remove `.` before dragHandle

```
  $('#sort').tableDnD({
            onDrop: function(table, row) {
              alert(row.id);
            }, 
            dragHandle: "dragHandle"
   });
```

See example [here](http://code.google.com/p/tablednd/source/browse/trunk/index.html?spec=svn12&r=12)

Comment: Does jquery and jquery.tablednd.js is loading ?? and table with `sort` as id exists??

Comment: yes they are loaded thats y it is working when i remove draghandle